# Conditional formatting in Excel according to today's date

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an Excel file that links to some documents, certificates and such, which are valid for a year. For example, since Feb 20, 2014 until Feb 20, 2015.

To the right, I have a column in which are the dates of expiry, and next to it a column that is a month earlier - when I should start thinking about contacting the 3rd party to send us the new certificate for the following year.

**Is there a way to make a date cell in excel be conditionally formatted (for example red background with while letters) depending on the date today?
For example, in that second column, all dates from Jan 20, 2015 until todays should be coloured red.**

Is that possible and how would one go about that?

Comment: Can anyone give an explanation is there something here that would account for the downvote?

Comment: Although I did not down vote this, my guess is it is for lack of research effort or showing what you have already attempted.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer I gave for a [previous question](https://superuser.com/a/790774/97028). Please realize it can not possibly give you the step by step for your scenario, but it will get you started.

You will need to modify it according to how your data is laid out, but it should work. There is a tutorial at the source below to help you learn how to do this.

In essence, you are going to use conditional formatting with a formula.

Create a rule and choose `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`

Below is what it looks like for one that is within 7 days of being overdue.

[image]

The formula is cut off in the image. It is `=IF(ISBLANK($J2), AND(MEDIAN(TODAY()+1,$E2,TODAY()+7)=$E2),"")`

Below is for those that are overdue.

[image]

I end up with two rules applied to the same range.

[image]

Again, you will have to make this work for your data, but it will work with three conditions. Follow the examples in the source linked below to learn how to do this. It's a great tool I use daily.

[Highlight due dates in Excel – Show items due, overdue and completed in different colors](http://chandoo.org/wp/2012/05/22/highlight-due-dates-excel/)

Comment: FYI to OP: The formula for the date one month prior to today is `DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())-1,DAY(TODAY()))`. There's also the `EDATE` function but it may or may not work on your version. `EDATE(TODAY(),-1)`